# Find within an existing find loop in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel spreadsheet where I have values in a form format, I need to convert them into tabular format. example -

```
Project ID/Name:    3001    Miscellaneous Improvements  
Location:   This is Project Location.   
Description:    This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description. This is the project description.
Justification:  This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification. This is the project Justification.
Duration:       Q1 2013 to  Ongoing     
Status:     This is some status
```

Each block starts with Project ID/Name, however, Description and Justification can vary according to the size of text they have. All the headings are in Column A. If I use Find for ProjectID - and use offset at a fixed length it works but if Justification and description are bigger or smaller they don't fall in correct place. Please help.

Comment: so each of those lines is a single string so cell `A6` is `Status: This is some status`? it's not A6=Status and B6=This is some status?

Comment: post code you have tried.

Comment: Description is not single line and so is Justification.

Comment: I am not able post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextToColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff193593(v=office.15).aspx). Example:

```
'Split this cells when find ':" or <TABS>
[A1:A6].TextToColumns Destination:=[A1], DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Tab:=True, OtherChar:=":", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to convert a vertical "form" into a table of data. I suggest adding that data to an existing table.

Here's the code.

You'll need to edit some variables (sheet/range names)

```
Public Sub test()
    'insert your code to get each Worksheet and it's column range here
    transferFormDataToTable Range("Sheet1!B1:B100"), Worksheets(2).ListObjects(1)
End Sub

Public Sub transferFormDataToTable(yourRangeB As Range, dbTable As ListObject)
    ' make a reference to the form data range
    Dim formRange As Range
    Set formRange = yourRangeB

    'create a new ListRow in your target table
    Dim listR As ListRow
    Set listR = dbTable.ListRows.Add

    'transfer the data from form to the new ListRow
    Dim lastHeader As String
    lastHeader = ""
    Dim targetColumnOffset As Integer
    targetColumnOffset = 0
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    currentColumn = 0
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To formRange.Count
        'if the row's header is not empty and different than previous row
        'then we'll know we have a new column of different type of data
        If lastHeader <> formRange(i).Offset(0, -1).Value And formRange(i).Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
            lastHeader = formRange(i).Offset(0, -1).Value
            targetColumnOffset = 0
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        End If

        'this loop captures data that might have been placed in columns to the right of the input cell
        Dim rowString As String
        rowString = ""
        Dim j As Integer
        j = 0
        Do While True
            If formRange(i).Offset(0, j).Value <> "" Then
                If rowString = "" And targetColumnOffset = 0 Then
                    rowString = formRange(i).Offset(0, j).Value
                Else
                    rowString = rowString & "; " & formRange(i).Offset(0, j).Value
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        If targetColumnOffset = 0 Then
            listR.Range(currentColumn).Value = rowString
        Else
            listR.Range(currentColumn).Value = listR.Range(currentColumn).Value & rowString
        End If

        targetColumnOffset = targetColumnOffset + 1

        'Exit the loop if it seems to get the end
        If formRange(i).Value = "" And formRange(i).Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then _
            Exit For
    Next i
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Excel has weird bugs occasionally when creating editing with VBA empty tables that have only 1 or 2 rows. I suggest using this macro only when your table has 3+ rows.
2. Send me a note if you want a much more complete version of this. Namely, a problem you might eventually have with this short version is that the code will screw up if a user switches columns around.

EDIT

3. I just adapted the code to your requirements. This is bound to get buggy eventually though. I'd really look into convincing the team about just how much they need to find a more appropriate tool. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Andre, Thanks for the reply. Actually it's not just that I have only these many values. There is lot of other junk values that I do not want in my table from the form. But I want all the project related values to be taken. I was looking for something like Find() within a find ?

Comment: How is your original data structured? Is it ColumnA-Header, ColumnB-Data? If it is, I'll edit the code example accordingly

Comment: Yes, However, description sometimes takes 2 rows sometimes 1 rows and same with Justification

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. I might tackle the fix to the algorithm within 2days. However, let me stress this: you need to inform your team to stop working that (crappy) way. Make a better form for people to use and use the macro above. Forms shouldn't have different cells everywhere. If they use it in a variable way, use the RowHeight instead to capture more text. (I also suggest using a proper project management program and not just Excel)

Comment: Andre, did you find sometime for me?

Comment: Just edited the text. It can get multiple rows and columns, just as long as the multiple rows follow each-other and have the same header or are empty.